# Weird margin at the top of the page

Tags: html, css, image, margin, space

I am getting crazy about my simple web. There is a unexplainable space between the top of the page and my image. Can someone explain me why?

The url: [http://2014.nahollaru.cz/](http://2014.nahollaru.cz)

my html

```
<body>
    <img src="img/top.png" border="0" />
```

my css

```
<style type="text/css">
/* --------- demo presentation------------ */
body {text-align: center;}
#header {margin-top:0px; height: 100px; width:800px; margin:0px auto; background: #000;}
#header p {text-align:center; font-style:italic;  color:#fff; font-family:Cambria; font-size:30px;}
#primary .obsah, #content .obsah, #secondary .obsah {text-align:justify; font-family:Cambria; color:#E6E8E1; font-size:15px; }
#primary p:hover, #content p:hover, #secondary p:hover {color:black;}
a{color:#E6E8E1;}
a:hover{color:black;}
#footer {padding:5px; height: 20px; width:800px; margin:0px auto; background: #000; color:#fff; font-family:Cambria; font-size:25px;}
/* --------------------------------------- */



/* ----- set width and center layout ----- */
#container {
    width:800px;
    margin:20px auto;
}
/* --------------------------------------- */




/* ----------- float columns ------------- */
#primary, #content, #secondary {
    float:left;
    width:266.667px;
    height:auto;
    padding: 50px 0;
    background-color:#fff;
    font-family:Cambria;
    color:#E6E8E1;
    text-align:justify;
}

#primary:hover, #content:hover, #secondary:hover {
    color:black;
}

#primary a:hover{
    color:black;
}
/* --------------------------------------- */




/* --------------------------------------- */
#footer {
    clear:both;
}
/* --------------------------------------- */
</style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

What you're seeing is the default margin on `body`. Just add this rule to the top of your styles:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: or preferably use a nice reset, which I can't say though, haven't done web in a while.

Comment: if you're not using a css framework, I'd recommend that you at least base your site on http://html5boilerplate.com, then stuff like this is solved for you.

Comment: To add onto this, try to find something like this that defaults a lot of elements (Many attributes can be plagued by this)